# The point of listener in code example

Tags: java, android, sockets, listener

I'm trying to create a simple client socket in Android OS and while searching around the web for materials, I stumbled upon an example (not really well written, since it has a few errors and an infinite loop, but it does its job as a simple example) which has a part of code I fail to comprehend, so I thought maybe this community could help me out and shed some light as to why this whole listener part is there and what purpose does it serve?
Here's the part of the code concerning that listener:

```
public interface OnListener {
    void listenerMethod(String text);//never invoked pretty much
}

public class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements OnListener {
    @Override
    public void listenerMethod(String text) {//this gets executed after send(View v) method, 'text' String variable contains the msgToSend from phone (from textfield above SEND button)
        sendMessage(text);//invoked by onStop with String variable == "bye"... and it gets stucked in a loop at this point
    }
}

private ClientTask myClientTask;
private OnListener listener;

public void addListener(OnListener listenerToAdd) {//this method is invoked by send(View v)
    this.listener = listenerToAdd;
}

public void send(View v) {//invoked when you press the Send button, empty strings do not get sent (they stop at a trycatch and don't execute any network thingies)
    addListener(myClientTask);//why does it add listener each time a msg is sent?
    if (listener != null)
        listener.listenerMethod(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_MsgToSend)) //this here gets the msg you typed into the editable textfield above SEND button
                .getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {//Restart button invokes this
    try {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.listenerMethod("bye");
        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Extremely common in the Android circles, an interface callback, the class that implements the interface, is passed into a class that is tightly bound to the interface and fires off the message to those implemented classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the callback pattern, the Hollywood principle "Don't call me, I'll call you". First it defines the Interface `OnListener` which the the class `ClientTask` implements and provides an implementation for. Now ClientTask is both a ClientTask class type and OnListener type. The addListener method just makes it possible to pass through the `ClientTask` which is of type `OnListener` since it implements that interface and that means we have access to the implementation of the method

`listenerMethod(String string)`

Later on we just call `listener.listenerMethod(EditText...blah)` which takes whatever String in the edit text and will go to the class which implements the OnListener (i.e. in our case our ClientTask) and send the message with the String that was present in the EditText

So everytime the send(View v) is invoked, the listenerMethod(String text) in ClientTask is also executed.

Comment: I do understand what gets executed after what as I've debugged this code step-by-step, but what I'm trying to understand is the purpose of it. What's the point, why does it has to `addListener` every time a message it sends? What does it help with? Is it some kind of implementing a new thread for the task? Why can't it just skip that whole listener part and call `sendMessage(text)` right away?

Comment: A socket is a connection where you send a stream of data, so every time you send something ia not necesarily the same message